# Is it possible to have an interactive background on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, desktop-customization

I would like to have say for example, a water background that interacts with my mouse click or hovers. Typically it would be a .swf file, but I have only found ways to make a video into a background. Is it possible to make not a video, but a "game" of some sort as a background? The question is originally for Windows 7, but I would accept any answers within the Windows 8 / 10 OS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Live Wallpaper" in windows 7 / 8 / 10 / 11 as Microsoft disabled active desktops from windows 7 onwards.
Most animated desktop wallpapers require money, but they do not have interaction.
Good Luck!